# Why does exec command thrown an error on running the following code?

Tags: python, database, unix, syntax, connection

This is the code :

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(krd_spot 7/5/2019 -df UYU_GOVT_RR -debug DISCFUNC |& less)
out = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
err = stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
print(out)
```

This is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-15-2085d261d263>", line 1
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(krd_spot 7/5/2019 -df UYU_GOVT_RR -debug DISCFUNC |& less)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

The command should be passed as a string:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("krd_spot 7/5/2019 -df UYU_GOVT_RR -debug DISCFUNC |& less")
```

Comment: Just replace your first line with the list I've posted